# Performing automated test for R shiny dashboard

Tags: r, unit-testing, testing, shiny, dashboard

Good day all,

I have spent quite some time looking into ways to perform unit test on my UI, specifically on my valuebox, progressbar, barcharts, etc. Firstly I am not exactly sure if "unit test" is the right term in this context so please kindly correct me if I am wrong. What I intend to do is to ensure that for example that the valuebox appears as intended (if I want 10 to appear on it, it should appear as 10 and not other number), the progressbar will progress accordingly to a reactive data.

I have looked into an R package called [shinytest](https://rstudio.github.io/shinytest/articles/shinytest.html) and they seem to have a snapshot approach which may not be feasible if we intend to extract data from a reactive database. I then tried out an [article](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/integration-testing.html) from R with regards to unit testing and was wondering if that is the right path for me.

Can I kindly get advice from experts that incorporate testing into their dashboard?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question might be a better suited for https://community.rstudio.com. The `testModule` method is still experimental, but unit testing can be done using the `testthat` pkg. Confirming that a valuebox renders a value (e.g., 10), can be done by writing a test that fetches the data, generates a valuebox, and evaluates the HTML markup for the desired value. You can do this without starting the Shiny server.

Comment: Does this help: https://rstudio.github.io/shinytest/articles/in-depth.html#dealing-with-dynamic-data-1. Of course, your application will load the dynamic data in production, but testing new features can be done with separate datasets that don't change (unless you need to change them)